# SQLAlchemy - How to make "django choices" using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In Django we can use very simple "choices" e.g.:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)
class Foo(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

How to make something like this using SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [custom types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/custom_types.html).

Example:

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types

class ChoiceType(types.TypeDecorator):

    impl = types.String

    def __init__(self, choices, **kw):
        self.choices = dict(choices)
        super(ChoiceType, self).__init__(**kw)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return [k for k, v in self.choices.iteritems() if v == value][0]

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return self.choices[value]
```

The use of it would look like:

```
    class Entity(Base):
        __tablename__ = "entity"
        height = Column(
            ChoiceType({"short": "short", "medium": "medium", "tall": "tall"}), nullable=False
        )
```

If you are using Python 3, you have to change iteritems() to items().

Answer (score 42):

I would probably go for [sqlalchemy_utils](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice)

Comment: I think this should be accepted answer as sqlalchemy_utils reduce self written code and provide more usefull stuff

Comment: Unfortunately ChoiceType from sqlalchemy_utils breaks the Flask-SQLAlchemy migration scripts as of versions 0.33.3 and 2.3, respectively. So there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 26):

SQLAlchemy has an Enum type, which functions like Django's "choices" field.

From the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html?highlight=enum#sqlalchemy.types.Enum):

'The Enum type will make use of the backend’s native “ENUM” type if one is available; otherwise, it uses a VARCHAR datatype and produces a CHECK constraint.'

```
import enum
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    one = 1
    two = 2
    three = 3


t = Table(
    'data', MetaData(),
    Column('value', Enum(MyEnum))
)

connection.execute(t.insert(), {"value": MyEnum.two})
assert connection.scalar(t.select()) is MyEnum.two
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: wouldn't this require a migration each time you add an option?

Comment: @tutuca You are 100% right. Been using an enum field for a while and another dev changed the python code w/o creating a migration and it caused an intense learning experience.

Comment: More concerning to me than the migration when adding an option, is the fact that it's "not safe" to remove values from the enum (in postgres, at least).

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21012.1459434338%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 0):

Adding an example to [@radeklos 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590469/1031191):

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy_utils import ChoiceType
Base = declarative_base()

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)
class Foo(Base):
    gender = ChoiceType(GENDER_CHOICES, impl=String(length=1))
```