# How to use choice field in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm from django, in django models, when we want to use `choices` in our field, we defined it like this:

```
class ListAlbum(models.Model):
    LIST_OF_ALBUM = (
        ('Shakira', 'shakira'),
        ('Don Jazy', 'Don Jazy'),
        ('Psquare', 'Psquare')
    )
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=20, choices=LIST_OF_ALBUM)
```

As a beginner in `flask`, I don't know how to use it in flask models.

Comment: Falsk don't have built in ORM.
It depends on what type of database and ORM you want to use.
For relational ones you can use e.g. SQLAlchemy or tortoise
https://tortoise.github.io/examples/pydantic.html
Do you want to use an ORM at all? Do you use a NoSQL database?
The answer will depend on these choices.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, but there is a similar question for SQLAlchemy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262943/sqlalchemy-how-to-make-django-choices-using-sqlalchemy